# How to search through manytomany objects in a modelform?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I haven't had much luck in finding something that can get me going in finding a solution.

Basically I have a modelform that I use to create events. In that model I have a person field in which its a manytomany value. What I want to do is to have a search box in which I can start typing in a name and the results keep decreasing based on additional characters I enter.

How could I possibly implement that search box functionality?

I'm able to pre-populate some of those objects but I want to dynamically query based on the name entered in the search box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [django-selectable](http://django-selectable.readthedocs.org/en/version-0.6.2/).

It's very clean and works with JQuery